# No resources of this type found under this subscription Azure Logic Apps

Tags: python, azure, smtp, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

I tried to create a workflow using Azure Logic Apps, I used Recurrence as my trigger (Daily) and Azure Function (Timer Trigger) as my Process to create some dataframe and export to csv, and both of them Dataframe, and CSV file need to send it via email.

At first, I use SMTP in my Azure Function, but it got an error when deployed on Azure (Auth Error). So my plan is using the logic app "Send Email".

But when I tried to deploy the my Azure Function I got an error, and I can't Create it on Logic Apps

```
No resources of this type found under this subscription.
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have tested this in our local environment , Below analysis are based on our observations.

In our local environment , we have created a logic app of both  `consumption based` & `standard based` with `recurrence` as trigger  tried to call `AZURE function`   from the logic apps.

1. If you are trying to add existing azure function in your logic app .You can add only `Http trigger functions`  in either standard based or consumption based logic app.

- Adding Http trigger functions to standard logic app :

[image]

- Adding Http trigger functions to consumption based  logic app :

[image]

2. If you function app has timer trigger or queue function & you are trying to add them in your logic app those functions are not getting populated as shown below

Adding timer trigger functions to Consumption based logic app:

[image]

Adding timer trigger functions to Standard based logic app:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When I tried to connect azure functions from logic app workflow. I got this issue "No resource of this type found under this subscription".

This is how I resolved this problem.

1. Created Http Trigger azure function "**testfunc**" through VS
2. Post **testfunc** to azure
3. Created Workflow "**testworkflow**" in azure logic app
4. Created Http Request Trigger
5. Call an azure function and point already created azure function "**testfunc**"
6. We will get "No resource of this type found under this subscription issue"
7. Add CORS to "**testfunc**" api and save

Now we could able to call an azure function without any problem

You can also refer
https://www.softwaredesigncorner.com/2022/10/how-to-resolve-no-resources-of-this.html